# Where can i find the: 1) cache hits and 2) cache lookup stats in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, caching, statistics, lookup

First of, the question is not: how to see SQL Server cache hit rate!
For that one i already know of a view that contains that precises statistic.

My question is in fact: where are the raw statistics from where the hit ratio is calculated?
Sql server, in msdn pages, states that the cache hit ratio is the total cache hits  divided by the total cache lookups. So I am assuming that the RDBMS is storing these two values somewhere.

Anyone know where i can access them?

Comment: the 2) :P was little bit to the left of where I clicked. 
:)
Space-time misplacemente, I think! :D

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the exact metrics you seek are available via the Dynamic Management View (DMV):

- [sys.dm_os_performance_counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187743.aspx)

For example:

```
Select *
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters
WHERE OBJECT_NAME='SQLServer:Buffer Manager'
```

You can also use the Windows Performance Monitor to review the Buffer Cache statistics:

- [The SQL Server Buffer Pool and
  Buffer Cache](http://www.johnsansom.com/index.php/2009/03/the-sql-server-buffer-pool-and-buffer-cache-hit-ratio/)

For detailed information regarding the metrics concerning SQL Server Buffer Management consult the reference:

- [SQL Server, Buffer Manager
  Object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189628.aspx)

To get detailed information regarding all of the SQL Server Memory space use the command:

```
DBCC memorystatus
```

*Note*: Regarding point 2) of the question, Page lookups == cache lookups and again this information is available in the afformentioned DMV.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your time!

The system view you mention in your post, sys.dm_os_performance_counters, i have discovered it a few days ago. The problem with that view, and the counters you mention is that they are all rates.
That is, they are giving me the rations and not the absolute values I seek. For instance, the page lookups you mentioned are: page lookups/sec. My desired is to retrieve the page lookups at two diferent points in time an determine the total page lookups for that period of time. Likewise for cachehits: that way I know exactly the time interval for which the ratio stands.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to SQL Server then you can start SQL Server Profiler which will show you all the queries running on database. Keep SQL Server Profiler running & start recorded web test (like in VSTS  Web Test).

At least looking at running trace will give you good idea of how many times db is accessed.

Suppose you query is

```
select * from customer
```

see how many times it occurs in trace.

Let's say 200 times

& number of test iterations, let's say 800.

Then 800/(800-200) = cache hit ratio.